# VB.net not recognizing network filepath

Tags: vb.net, network-programming

Problem: I have a users that upload dictations from handheld recorders. When docked, the files migrate from the handset to a TEMP folder location. From there software on the computer uploads the files to a server. When there is an issue, the files hang in the TEMP location.

Solution: Originally tried copying files, if present using robocopy, however, duplicate name and naming convention restrictions forced a change in approach. I have decided to create a small program to scan the file directory on all PCs in the domain. If the TEMP folder contains files, the output of computer name will be displayed in a Listbox. (I have yet to setup a parse to show just the name so right now it shows the full filepath).

Issue: I have error checking in place to verify if the Filepath Exists but is empty, Exists and contains files, and lastly, Does not Exist. The issue is that the program says every File directory "does not exist." I have verified that the path does exists and that I can UNC to it from the same machine that I am launching the Debug on. I have tested as a domain admin as well. I've also tried with and without encompassing quotes on the file path (there are spaces in the filepath). The HIGH and LOW fields are the lowest and highest asset tag info to scan (sets scope of assets to scan).

Code (VB.Net 2010):

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Main

    Private Sub btnScan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnScan.Click
        Dim fs, oFolder
        Dim strFolderPath As String
        Dim count As Integer
        Dim low As Integer
        Dim high As Integer
        Dim company As String = "\\Company"
        Dim path As String = "\c$\Program Files\Speech Machines\SubSpace\temp"
        Dim countpath As String = ""
        lstNames.Items.Clear()
        low = CInt(txtLow.Text)
        high = CInt(txtHigh.Text)
        For count = low To high
            countpath = count.ToString
            fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            strFolderPath = (Chr(34) + oah + countpath + path + Chr(34))
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(strFolderPath) Then
                oFolder = fs.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
                If (oFolder.files.count = 0) Then
                    'folder is Empty
                    lstNames.Items.Add(oah + countpath + " " + "Empty")
                Else
                    ' folder isn't empty
                    lstNames.Items.Add(oah + countpath + " " + "Files Contained: " & oFolder.files.count)
                End If
                fs = Nothing
            Else
                'folder does not exist
                lstNames.Items.Add(strFolderPath + " " + "Does not exist")
            End If
        Next
        'completion message
        MessageBox.Show("Scanning Complete")
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveListToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveListToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
        'Prompt the user for a file name to save to.
        If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'Create the file to save to.
            Dim output As New IO.StreamWriter(sfd.FileName)
            'Write lines of text to the file.
            For Each item As Object In lstNames.Items
                output.WriteLine(lstNames.GetItemText(item))
            Next item
            'Close the file.
            output.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Did you try debugging to the If statement that checks for the directory and see what value is being passed? It sounds like a simple directory formatting problem.

Comment: I thought the same thing so I played around with it a little bit. The program itself will export the filepath and I can see what filepath it is reaching out to. So....I tried to UNC to the direct output without success. I added the char(34) to flank the filepath so it showed in quotes (spaces in filepath). I can UNC without issue with the quotes. So, I am pretty sure that the path being passed is proper. Is there any other test you might recommend? I do this stuff very rarely so any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: What does strFolderPath hold right at the If check?

Comment: Ok it shows (including quotes)   "\\Company[numberIinput]\c$\Program Files\Speech Machines\SubSpace\temp"

Comment: I verified this by adding
    messagebox.show(strFolderPath) just before the IF check.

Comment: For starters, I know you don't need char(34) there. And secondly, whatever is in that string when it hits the My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists check, should be copy/pasteable into explorer directly and load the directory. If it fails there, it will fail in your program.

Comment: I did not know that. I will give that a try! Thank you. Also...The quotes are not necessary if there are spaces in the filepath? I thought that would be necessary or it would stop reading at the "space."

Comment: No, spaces are fine. You're thinking of command prompts where quotations are needed.

Comment: Understood. Picking this up later today to test. Putting out a few fires now. Thank you again Keith!

Comment: ok...so running the line in EXPLORER told me I do not have sufficient privileges. Is there a way or a code that will allow the commands to run under an elevated account? I do have the general admin account credentials, though they do not match my standard login credentials which is my current testing account. Additionally, the program fails when being run as the admin account regardless.

Comment: I believe that ventures into the land of network/administration access. You should be able to access that folder path if your network privileges are set up properly. I'd focus on that before code at this point. I don't know enough about network administration to help you further. :\

Comment: I appreciate all of your help! I had added network to the tags on this post but someone removed it....sigh...